# How do you say x in x language? What's the English/Spanish word for x?

Tags: grammaticality, questions

Is it correct to ask "how do you say 'tower' in Spanish?" or should we actually ask "what's the Spanish word for 'tower'?" Some people say that if I ask "how do you say..." the answer would be *softly, loudly* etc., as if *how* was functioning as an adverb of manner and that was its only function. So, the correct question would be "what's the Spanish word for..."

What do you think? is there any grammar rule that could help me understand the difference between these two questions?

Comment: There's no real difference. There are millions of ways to say anything. But if you want to learn the word for x in X language, ask in X language. For instance, _¿Cómo se dice «tower» en Español?_

Comment: But is it or is it not grammatically correct to ask HOW do you say ...?

Comment: Actually, the difference in how you ask is that if you ask for just the word, that's what you'll get.  But if you ask *how* do you say X, you might get the word or a phrase or idiom that is "how" the natives would say x.

Comment: But you're picking up grains of sand one by one if you ask word by word. You'll never get to the beach that way.

Comment: These things are beside the point. What the OP appears to want is to be reassured that someone will not take the opportunity to seize upon the innate ambiguity of the "How do you V ...?" trope for humorous purposes. Like Liberace's joke when asked how he played the piano with all those gigantic rings, he'd reply "Very well."

Comment: "How do you get to Carnegie Hall?" You can misinterpret anything. The normal way to say it is "How do you say X?"

Comment: Reminds me of the old joke, "*My dog has no nose*" / "*How does he smell?*" / "*Terrible!*"

Comment: To @Robusto's point, yes, some joker might take you *literally* when you ask "how do you say...", but in English, "how do you say..." is a well-understood idiom and most people will perfectly understand what you're asking.

Comment: "Doctor, it hurts when I press my belly. It also hurts when I press my chest." // "I see. It appears your finger is broken."

Comment: @Mitch, *practice, practice, practice!"* lol!

Comment: Hey, it's not my misunderstanding. OP said "...as if how was functioning as an adverb of manner and that was its only function." Read the friggin' post. And my intention was not to hijack the comments into a daisychain of examples of what I described.

Answer (score 4):

As Kristina says, *what's the word for...* asks for a specific word, while *how do you say...* could be a word or a phrase.

Both ways are perfectly fine and idiomatic. A pedant myself, the argument "*how* asks for an adverb of manner" sounds like a joke to me, wordplay, not something one would say in all seriousness. You can express a "manner" in more ways than just by a single adverb; a sequence of sounds (like a phrase) is a manner or way to express a thought, a way of saying something.

Comment: Not to be pedantic, but don't you mean "To a pedant like myself, the argument ... sounds like a joke?"

Comment: @Robusto: I thought about it, but decided it had to be an absolute construction, of the type *her mother dead, she fled the country*.

Comment: "Her mother dead, she ..." is fine. "A pedant myself, the argument ... sounds" is a dangling participial clause.

Comment: @Robusto: What participle?

Comment: It's implied: "[Being] a pedant myself, ..."

Comment: @Robusto: so you're changing the construction he used to something quite different, and then complaining about the thing you changed it to. I think that qualifies as a Type 2.b.(ii).k' pedantry.

Comment: But the general, and important, point is that lots of things we say are _formally_ ambiguous, but rather few of them are ambiguous in practice, mostly because pragmatic principles (such as Gricean implicatures) take care of it for us.

Comment: @ColinFine: That is absolutely true (although neither "softly" nor "pequeño" is more ambiguous than the other, in my opinion).

Comment: @ColinFine: I didn't change the construction. Also, any apprentice pedant would know that the article in question is Type 2.c.(ii).k. It's a rookie mistake, but I will let it go with a warning this time.

Comment: It isn’t a dangling participial clause, but it is a dangling modifier. “A pedant myself, I find the argument …” would work, though.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: Yes, that was the alternative I considered, but *I find the argument "how asks for an adverb of manner" sounds like a joke* seems infelicitous. So I went for the absolute construction. And it isn't a dangling modifier, because an absolute construction does not modify anything. You might say absolute constructions are not allowed if the same person object is also a regular constituent in the clause, but...

Comment: You’re right, of course—dangling appositive was what I meant.